# Echo out the sum of a MYSQL column

Tags: php, mysql

Pretty simple script here which is mostly working. It is echoing successfully the entire MySQL query except the sum total of the donations. What I want it to do is echo out the total donations by one user, not all donations.

Here is the script.

```
<?php
require_once("models/config.php");


 $id=$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];

$sql = "SELECT persons.personid, persons.firstname, persons.surname, donations.amount,     SUM(donations.amount), donations.donation_type, donations.donation_date, donations.event
FROM persons, donations
WHERE persons.personid = donations.personid = '$id'
ORDER BY personid";

$results = $mysqli->query($sql);

 echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='10'>";
    echo "<tr> <th>First Name</th> <th>Surname</th> <th>Donation Type</th> <th>Donation     Amount</th> <th>Donation Event</th> <th>Donation Date</th></tr>";
if($results->num_rows) {
while($row = $results->fetch_object()) {
echo "<tr>";
            echo '<td>' . $row->firstname . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $row->surname . '</td>';
           echo '<td>' . $row->donation_type . '</td>';
           echo '<td>' . $row->event . '</td>';
           echo '<td>  $'.$row->amount. '</td>';
           echo '<td>' . $row->donation_date . '</td>';
  echo "</tr>";
  echo "</table>"; 

  echo $row->sum(amount);
}
} else {
echo "</table>";
  echo 'No results';
}

?>
```

I get this error code: "Fatal error: Call to undefined method stdClass::sum() in ..." What could the trouble be - the MYSQL query, the PHP echo? Do I need to do another Query just for the total (something I really don't want to do)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I got this figured out. For those who want to learn, this is how you get it.

The SQL query has to be amended to:

```
 SELECT persons.personid, persons.firstname, persons.surname, donations.amount,        donations.donation_type, donations.donation_date, donations.event
 FROM persons
 INNER JOIN donations ON persons.personid = donations.personid
 AND donations.personid =  '$id'";
```

Then the table output was wrong. I put the end table tag too early and was cutting off all the outputs. Then one needs to create a variable to do the sum of all the donations. It looks like this:

```
$results = $mysqli->query($sql);

echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='10'>";
echo "<tr> <th>First Name</th> <th>Surname</th> <th>Donation Type</th> <th>Donation     Event</th> <th>Donation Amount</th> <th>Donation Date</th></tr>";
$totaldonations = 0;
if($results->num_rows) {

while($row = $results->fetch_object()) {
echo "<tr>";
echo '<td>' . $row->firstname . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $row->surname . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $row->donation_type . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $row->event . '</td>';
echo '<td> $'.$row->amount. '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $row->donation_date . '</td>';
echo "</tr>";

$totaldonations = $totaldonations + $row->amount;

}
}
 else {
echo 'No results';
}
echo "</table>";
echo "Total of Donations:  $".$totaldonations;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your query give some name to this column

```
SUM(donations.amount) as sum_amount
```

Then print it with `echo $row->sum_amount`

Comment: This only works if you want to get the total amount for a given user specified in the `WHERE` clause

Comment: he said total donations for one user

Comment: Right. But he coded a table showing the total for each user, so I clarified the answer ;-)

Comment: sorry it's not working. My SQL Query looks like this. `$sql = "SELECT persons.personid, persons.firstname, persons.surname, donations.amount, SUM(donations.amount) as sum_amount, donations.donation_type, donations.donation_date, donations.event
FROM persons, donations
WHERE persons.personid = donations.personid = '$id'
ORDER BY personid";` is that done correctly?

Comment: do you want your query to return all details for only single user?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is wrong with PHP's echo or your SQL really. It seems that you're telling PHP to call $row's "sum" method, which doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Now that I understand your desired output better:

1. Removing SUM(donations.amount) from your SQL will give you multiple rows (one per donation) rather than a single row per user queried
2. The best solution may be to use a PHP variable (initialized to 0) to which the $row->amount is added each time the code goes through the while loop's body. Once the loop is done, echo this variable, which is the sum of all the user's donations.

Comment: It doesn't return any results with your suggested query.

Comment: Hi, yes, using that variable set to 0 is what was needed. But my query was messed up to begin with.